# Adding a polyfill for the missing crypto module

Tags: reactjs, cryptography, polyfills, fallback, webpack.config.js

I am trying to set up mysql database to use it with React, but I am getting multiple errors for Connection.js, Protocol.js, Timer.js, Query.js:
-Can't resolve 'crypto'
-Can't resolve 'net'
-Can't resolve 'tls'.

I installed modules and I created in root webpack.config.js with fallbacks. The one in react-scripts was too complex for me and I didn't know what to change it. I added in package.json this:
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start --config ./path/to/webpack.config.js",

The webpack file I created is ignored by React. Is there a way to apply fallbacks in this way?
What can I do to fix this? None of the other answers helped.